# Listening for url change in React Native Expo WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I would like to open a web browser in React native expo which loads up a url,  I then want to listen for a particular URL to be hit, at this point I want it to run some code and then close the browser window.

I've been trying to use Expo's WebBrowser for this.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/

```
async componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener("url", this.handleOpenURL);
}

handleOpenURL(event) {
    console.log(event.url);
    // do something here then dismiss the browser
}
```

... further on down the code I have this on a button press

```
let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('www.exampleurl.com');
```

This opens up the web page but does not ever hit the handleOpenUrl code, can this be done and if so has anyone got an example?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your handleOpenURL function will run only when someone opens a url that redirects to your app, it does not monitor the session of WebBrowser.

If you can control the backend, then you can use redirect link and `AuthSession` by exco given that . You can do something like:

```
import { AuthSession } from 'expo';

let authResult = await AuthSession.startAsync({
                authUrl: `https://myserverurl.com/?` +
                     `redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}`
            });

// This part will run after browsing session is over
console.log(authResult)
```